# userform_initialize() : continue to run macro while userform shows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform to display a "Wait for a second" kind of message and I put a macro inside userform_initialize() that I'd like to have running when the userform is called to show up.

Instead, when i call for userform_show() in other part of the code, it displays userform and everything is stopped until I click on red box to close userform.

How can I make the macro run in background? My need is to have the message displayed only while the action in macro is processed

Answer (score 0):

Found answer by myself : set ShowModal property to False

Comment: You can also use `Userform1.Show vbModeless`

Comment: thanks @SiddharthRout, will have a look, didn't know that property either